# parent scope is not binding to custom directive iso scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my directive:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('commentsDirective', [])

    .directive('mngComments', mngComments)

    function mngComments() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: { },
            templateUrl: '/comments/comments.html',
            controller: 'CommentsController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: {   
                moment: '=',
                comments: '=',
                showComments: '='
            }
        };
    };
})();
```

Here is how I am using it and passing values in:

```
<div mng-comments moment="vm.moments[0]" comments="vm.comments" showComments="true"></div>
```

Notice how I have hard-coded "true" into showComments.  Yet in my comments.html file:

```
comments {{vm.showComments}}
```

It displays {{vm.showComments}} with no value Its just comments.  vm.moments and vm.comments is correctly being passed.

Comment: Use "show-comments" in your html. In the markup camel case becomes a hyphenated version twoWords becomes two-words.

Comment: I can't believe it was so simpe I thought that hyphenated thing applied to just the name of the directive - How annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function() {
    angular.module('commentsDirective', [])

    .directive('mngComments', mngComments)

    function mngComments() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: { },
            template: '<div>test {{vm.showComments}}</div>',
            controller: function(){},
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: {   
                moment: '=',
                comments: '=',
                showComments: '='
            }
        };
    };
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="commentsDirective">
  <div mng-comments
       moment="vm.moments[0]"
       comments="vm.comments"
       show-comments="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

As indicated in the comments just use hyphen case in the HTML for bindings/scope properties that are in the javascript. HTML is not case sensitive so the - is used instead of camel casing.